# Terminal syscalls in Assembly

Tags: terminal, console, system-calls, x86, assembly

I would like to write a chess engine for Linux.
It will be in pure X64 Assembly language without any C/C++ or any other high level languages external libraries.
It will run in full screen text/console/terminal mode. No GUI.
It will use Unicode characters to display the chess pieces.
I know how to make it in Windows Console API.
Which Linux kernel syscalls are relevant to directly access the terminal and to change the font to one that supports Unicode?
I obviously researched it but found very little info, mostly for 32 bit with int 0x80 calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interacting with the console in Linux doesn’t involve many system calls — mostly [`open`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [`write`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) and [`ioctl`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html). You’ll find some documentation of relevant ioctls in [`man ioctl_console`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_console.2.html) and [`man ioctl_tty`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_tty.2.html), but many ioctls are undocumented (for example [`KDFONTOP`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/710885/86440)) and you’ll need to peruse the kernel source code to understand them. You’ll also need [`man console_codes`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) which describes escape codes usable on the console.

It would probably be easier to look at [programs which implement similar features](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303713/86440) and reproduce what they’re doing.